# Best way to match vanity URLs with an "s" or no "s" at the end

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, http-redirect

A common problem when creating a vanity or redirect URL is that users might leave the plural off the end.

What's the best way to match all of the following?:

- /park**s**project**s**
- /park**s**project
- /parkproject
- /parkproject**s**

`^/park[s|*]project*$` ?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What constitutes “*best*” without specifying discrete parameters for measurement is arbitrary/opinion-based at best. However, could you not simply use `^/parks?projects?$` …?

Comment: Why do you even put a `\D` there at all?

Comment: According to regexer, no @esqew, that's doesn't work. https://regexr.com/7pidd

Comment: @krystleto If you change [your regexr to use individual test cases](https://regexr.com/7pids) (or turn on the multiline/`m` option) instead of having it treat your linebreak-separated values as one big input, it does indeed work. Be sure you're using the right RegExp engine though dependent on where in the stack you're enforcing these regular expressions; JavaScript's regular expression engine (the one you selected in your regexr above) doesn't always treat things the same way as Wordpress/PHP (PCRE) would.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `^\/parks?projects?$`. This regex matches all the cases in your example, tested on regex101.com

The `?` after the `s` means that the letter is optional and might not be there.

If you want the regex to match your string anywhere in the content, such as an URL or as part of a more complex string, you can use `\/parks?projects?` without beginning and ending markers.

[regex101.com proof that the regex works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS3qH.jpg)

If you have more examples I could be more precise.

Comment: *"The square brackets for the `s` are necessary"*: that is not true.

Comment: You are correct @trincot, it does work also without them. I guess the difference with the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699237/best-way-to-match-vanity-urls-with-an-s-or-no-s-at-the-end/77699790#comment136981039_77699237) is that the `/` is escaped in my regex

Comment: `/` is not special in regex patterns. It does not need to be escaped.  (Unless it's being used as a delimiter by the regex literal/operator. But the pattern is not being used in such here.)